# DBMS_shceduler job executes select statements on creation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dbms-scheduler

I am trying to set-up an auction house in oracle sql for practice.
I want to make DBMS jobs for each item, for when the the sysdate is equals to the end of the auction, it fires, and sells the item.

I have this procedure 'sell' that puts up new items for sale. and at the end i have this: (ident is the id of the item) 
Itt calls a function that puts the money on the correct account.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sell()
...
    begin
             dbms_scheduler.create_job 
        (  
          job_name      =>  'Item_Job'||to_char(ident),  
          job_type      =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',  
          job_action    =>  'pay_the_seller('||to_char(ident)||');',  
          start_date    =>  pEnd_date,  
          enabled       =>  TRUE,  
          auto_drop     =>  TRUE,  
        end;
END;
```

The problem is that it seems to execute the 'pay_the_seller' proc. at the time when the job is created not at the start_date.

For example if the starting bid is 1 on the item, when the job fires it is going to add 1 the the account, even though i changed the bid in the meantime.

EDIT:
in the 'pay_the_seller()' procedure SELECT statements are executed when the job is created, but the UPDATE isn't.

How can i make the SELECT not to execute immediately?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pay_the_seller(
  pItem_id auctions.item_id%TYPE)
AS
  seller_name accounts.username%TYPE;
  price auctions.price1%TYPE;
  buyer_name accounts.username%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT seller INTO seller_name FROM auctions WHERE item_id = pItem_id;
  SELECT price1 INTO price FROM AUCTIONS WHERE item_id = pItem_id;
  SELECT buyer INTO buyer_name FROM auctions WHERE item_id = pItem_id;

  UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + price WHERE username = seller_name;
END pay_the_seller;
```

Comment: It seems quite likely that the problem is in the `pay_the_seller()` routine or some other part of the code, such as the mechanism for setting value of `pEnd_date` argument. The one thing you can be sure of is that DBMS_SCHEDULER is executing the job when you told it to run and not when you create it. I'm afraid you will have to debug this.

Comment: By the way, an auction app is a really good problem domain for practising SQL,  I'm going to nick the idea for a blog post I'm writing ;-)

Comment: Thanks, you were right. The problem is in the pay_the_seller(). It executes the SELECT statements when the job is created. I wonder why.

Comment: That's highly unlikely.  I think it much more likely that you have a bug.  Perhaps the higher bids have not been committed before the job ran.  As an aside, if you were doing this for real, you'd realistically have one job that ran periodically (every minute, for example) that closed out all the auctions that finished since the last run.  If you're eBay, you wouldn't want millions of jobs waiting to run.

Comment: Wow thank you i spent the last day trying to fix this and the only thing i was missing was a 'commit;'. Feeling dumb.